# Does a set of basis vectors have to be linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The definition for a set of vectors to be considered a basis for $R^n$ is that 1) this set spans $R^n$ - any vector in $R^n$ can be written as a combination of this set and 2) this set is linearly independent.

Extending this analogy to vector spaces, $V$, from the below article, it states "a set B of elements (vectors) in a vector space V is called a $\textbf{basis}$, if every element of V may be written in a unique way as a (finite) linear combination of elements of B."

Then, it goes on to say "B is a $\textbf{basis}$ if its elements are linearly independent and every element of V is a linear combination of elements of B. In more general terms, a basis is a linearly independent spanning set."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)

So, is a set $B$ considered a basis if everything in $V$ can be written with $B$ and $B$ must be linearly independent? Or, is $B$ a basis solely based on the fact that everything in $V$ can be written with $B$?

Comment: "Extending this analogy to vector spaces, V, from the below article" -- You didn't include the article in question.

Comment: @Art Would you want to call $V$ itself a basis?

Comment: Wouldn't $V$ include the basis?

Comment: Note that the second paragrpah has an extra word: **unique**. I think thismay be the source of some of your confusion. If you require that every element may be written **in a unique way** as a linear combination of elements of $B$, then this *implies* that $B$ is linearly independent. In general: a set $B$ spans if and only if every element of $V$ can be written as a linear combination of elements of $B$ in **at least one way**. A set $B$ is linearly independent if and only if every element of $V$ can be written as a linear combination of elements of $B$ in **at most one way**. (Cont)

Comment: And a set $B$ is a basis if and only if every element of $V$ can be written as a linear combination of elements of $B$ in **exactly one way** (which yields that $B$ is both a spanning set and linearly independent).

Comment: Hi @ArturoMagidin, I can get your point. Lets say we have two vectors $a$ and $b$ to be linearly independent, and they form a vector $c$, such that $c = a + b$. Now, if we have another vector $d$ that depends on $c$ and $a$, such that $d = c + 2a$, then we can substitute it as $d = a + b + 2a \to 3a + b$. So at last, $d$ depends on $a$ and $b$ only. Similarly if $b$ would have written in from of $a$ then there would be only one ($a$) vector as linearly independent (_But I also see it as dependant on $b$ somehow , that's a different story_)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove any confusion:

A Basis $B$ of a vector space $V$ is a subset $B \subset V$ such that

- $span(B) = V$ **and**
- $B$ is linearly independent

Answer (score 4):

The section where it says "written in a unique way" is equivalent to linear independence. I think this is where some confusion may have arisen.

Your first concluding statement is correct. The second isn't. The basis must be linearly independent; either said explicitely or with the magic word "uniquely" added to your second statement to make it implicitely so.

Answer (score 2):

The key element in the definition is “in a unique way”.

A set of vectors by definition is linear dependent if there's a linear combination with non-zero coefficients of them that gives the zero vector. Since the linear combination with all coefficients equal zero also gives the zero vector, this quite directly says that the zero vector can be written in more than one way. And since you can add the zero vector to any other vector without changing it, the same is then true of any other vector as well.

Comment: So basically, if the basis is not linearly independent, vector V can be expressed in multiple ways, which is undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

For $B$ to be a basis, linear independence of the elements of $B$ is required. That's the definition.

If you remove the independence condition, then it's no longer called a basis.

Answer (score 0):

**Definition.** A collection of vectors $\{v_1,\dotsc,v_d\}$ is a *basis* of a vector space $V$ if $\{v_1,\dotsc,v_d\}$ is linearly independent and $\operatorname{Span}\{v_1,\dotsc,v_d\}=V$.

Given this definition, there are a few things we can say.

**Theorem 1.** Suppose that $\{v_1,\dotsc,v_d\}$ and $\{w_1,\dotsc,w_{d^\prime}\}$ are two bases of a vector space $V$. Then $d=d^\prime$.

Theorem 1 allows us to define the *dimension* of $V$.

**Definition.** Suppose that $\{v_1,\dotsc,v_d\}$ is a basis of a vector space $V$. The *dimension* of $V$ is $\dim(V)=d$.

It turns out that we only need to check one of the two axioms defining a basis if we happen to know the dimension of our vector space.

**Theorem 2.** Suppose that $\dim(V)=d$ and consider a collection of vectors $\{v_1,\dotsc,v_d\}$ in $V$. Then $\{v_1,\dotsc,v_d\}$ is linearly independent if and only if $\operatorname{Span}\{v_1,\dotsc,v_d\}=V$.

For example, suppose that we know that $\dim(\Bbb R^3)=3$. Then to verify if the collection $$\{\left\langle2,\,-1,\,1\right\rangle, \left\langle0,\,2,\,1\right\rangle, \left\langle1,\,-2,\,0\right\rangle\}$$ is a basis of $\Bbb R^3$, we need only check that $$\operatorname{Span}\{\left\langle2,\,-1,\,1\right\rangle, \left\langle0,\,2,\,1\right\rangle, \left\langle1,\,-2,\,0\right\rangle\}=\Bbb R^3$$ and we don't have to check that the collection is linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already answered pretty well, I am adding more explanation to it based on my understanding and learnings so far.

From the Cambridge dictionary word [unique](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unique) means,

> something that is unique is unusual or the **only one of its type**

In the context of Linear Algebra, a vector is "*only one of its type*" [iff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if), there is **no linear combination exists which can form that vector**.

That means the following equation is true, only when $x = y = 0$.
$$
x\vec a + y \vec b = \mathbf{\vec 0}
$$

In terms of logic (*I might be incorrect here*),
$$
\forall x, \neg (\vec{a} = x\vec{b})
$$

Here is a PJ for you: "Since my answer depends on other answers, *it's dependant*."

Also, I can understand this confusion, as I am too get confused a lot while learning Maths in English (or any natural language per se).

**Note:** If you find any problem in my answer, please help me correct it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you think you might be incorrect why not try an prove it?